# Javascript: Dynamic Generation of a Div

Tags: javascript

I have several vertically stacks divs and I want to have a div appear when I click a button within each of these divs. The div that I want to appear will be the exact same for each appearance with the exception of an id associating it with the outer div.  How do I do this in Javascript?

I assume I should use the createElement() within Javascript, but how do I append it to the end of a specific element.  Also, when creating an element, I have to hardcode the html in the Javascript file.  Is there anyway to leave the element within the html design file.  I want to seperate design from code as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Clone Node

```
var clone = myDiv.cloneNode();
```

---

### Example ([live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gcFMd/10/)):

HTML

```
<div>
    <input type="button" onclick="functionClone(this);" value="Dolly"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="functionClone(this);" value="Dolly_1"/>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
functionClone = function(subject){
    var clonenode = subject.cloneNode(true);
    subject.value = subject.value + '\'s been cloned!';
    subject.disabled = true;
    insertElementAfter(subject, clonenode);
}     

insertElementAfter = function(subject, newElement){
    subject.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement,subject.nextSibling);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and the neat live demo! When I click the "Dolly" button, I want to append a div below the "Dolly" button.

Answer (score 0):

To append an element below your div use this:

```
subject.parentNode.appendChild(clonenode)
```